# how many servers does stack run on?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, server

i just wanted to know how many servers Stack Overflow runs on, with 240,000 users on the site, im thinking they have 1,000 of servers? but i wondered if you guys knew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be one server for each 240 people.. It's a bit overkill don't you think?

Servers can handle several connections per second; I'm not sure about the stack overflow architecture, but I work for a website where we have a bit over 11 million pageviews per month, and we have only 4 servers: two web servers for dynamic files, one for static files, and one db server.

Comment: oh thanks you just made my day, i wanted to create a website thats going to have hopefully a lot of users, and im only running two servers, one for the web, one for database server. can i just ask you if needed to put static content, shall i put it in the web server or the db server, and where would i put the memcached memory! if that makes sense

Comment: If I were you i'd worry about the site (and content) first (and worry about scalability when you need it ;-)

Comment: but im so obsessed with performance, i would rather have an ugly site with high performance, then a good loking one, really, and this is just my uni project so its not something sireous, its more to do with learning at the momment

Answer (score 6):

That's also slightly outdated information. That is discussing The OR datacenter we are moving out of.

In the new DC we are running:

- 10 Window 2008 Webservers on Dell R610's
- 2 windows DB servers on Dell R710s
- 2 HA Proxy load balencers
- A pair of Dell Servers Running Ubuntu acting as routers.
- A few backend management server - backup, monitoring, etc.

If your are interesting in our infrastructure Kyle and I talk about it on [The serverfault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com)

Answer (score 2):

Lots of useful information (and links) can be found in [this elaborate answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy/10370#10370).

```
ThinkServer RS110 1U - web tier (x6 - two host Stack Overflow)
ThinkServer RD120 2U - database tier (x2 - one primary, one backup)
```

So that's 8 instead of 1000. You might have overestimated (a bit).

Comment: wow thats amazing, and stackoverflow has high traffic

Comment: @getaway - Well, that goes to show just how powerful a well-managed set of servers can be.

Comment: @George Edison, I suspect the way the software was designed is just as important is the server management.

Comment: @Zoredache: For sure.

Comment: a good sense , i think !